# ASP.NET Web API is showing objects in JSON that I didn't ask for

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have a Web API with ASP.NET and I'm trying to return some data, but it's causing issues as it is referencing objects I don't want to be referenced.

The class structure in this case is the following:

**Entitats** (Entities), **Equips** (Teams) and **Esports** (Sports)

An **Entity** has many **Teams**, and one **Team** has just one **Sport**.

I am using Entity Framework and the Objects have the relationships both ways; a **Sport** has many **Teams**, and a **Team** has an **Entity**.

Here is the query I do to get an Entity with its Team, and each Team with its sport.

```
 entitats _entitat = (
                   from e in db.entitats
                       .Include("equips.esports")
                   where e.id == id
                   select e
               ).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should give me exactly what I want, the problem is that in the first Team, when it shows me the Sport, the Sport contains all other Teams (from this Entity) that have the same Sport, and then when it's time to show them on the Team array it uses $ref and $id.

```
"$id": "1",
"equips": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "activitats_concedides": [],
        "activitats_demanades": [],
        "categories": null,
        "categories_competicio": null,
        "competicions": null,
        "entitats": {
            "$ref": "1"
        },
        "esports": {
            "$id": "3",
            // These shouldn't even be here
            "equips": [
                {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "4",
                    "activitats_concedides": [],
                    "activitats_demanades": [],
                    "categories": null,
                    "categories_competicio": null,
                    "competicions": null,
                    "entitats": {
                        "$ref": "1"
                    },
                    "esports": {
                        "$ref": "3"
                    },
                    "sexes": null,
                    "id": 8,
                    "nom": "Test 2",
                    "id_entitat": 1,
                    "id_categoria": 3,
                    "id_esport": 1,
                    "id_competicio": 2,
                    "id_categoria_competicio": null,
                    "id_sexe": 3,
                    "borrat": false
                },
                {
                    "$id": "5",
                    "activitats_concedides": [],
                    "activitats_demanades": [],
                    "categories": null,
                    "categories_competicio": null,
                    "competicions": null,
                    "entitats": {
                        "$ref": "1"
                    },
                    "esports": {
                        "$ref": "3"
                    },
                    "sexes": null,
                    "id": 9,
                    "nom": "Test 3",
                    "id_entitat": 1,
                    "id_categoria": 2,
                    "id_esport": 1,
                    "id_competicio": 2,
                    "id_categoria_competicio": null,
                    "id_sexe": 2,
                    "borrat": false
                },
                {
                    "$id": "6",
                    "activitats_concedides": [],
                    "activitats_demanades": [],
                    "categories": null,
                    "categories_competicio": null,
                    "competicions": null,
                    "entitats": {
                        "$ref": "1"
                    },
                    "esports": {
                        "$ref": "3"
                    },
                    "sexes": null,
                    "id": 10,
                    "nom": "prova",
                    "id_entitat": 1,
                    "id_categoria": 3,
                    "id_esport": 1,
                    "id_competicio": 2,
                    "id_categoria_competicio": null,
                    "id_sexe": 2,
                    "borrat": false
                }
            ],
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "Futbol"
        },
        "sexes": null,
        "id": 3,
        "nom": "Test 1",
        "id_entitat": 1,
        "id_categoria": 6,
        "id_esport": 1,
        "id_competicio": 1,
        "id_categoria_competicio": null,
        "id_sexe": 1,
        "borrat": false
    },
    {
        "$ref": "4" // These should be the "full" objects
    },
    {
        "$ref": "5"
    },
    {
        "$ref": "6"
    }
],
"telefons": [],
"id": 1,
"nom": "Futbol Club Sant Cugat del Valles",
"direccio": "Sample Carrer 1",
"cif": "B12345678",
"temporada": "2019                ",
"correu": "entitat1@test.com",
"facebook": null,
"instagram": null,
"twitter": null,
"password": "8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92",
"borrat": true}
```

I didn't ask the Teams of each Sport, so I don't know why it's showing them. The same happens with the Teams' Entity, in this case, it's not an issue because it doesn't mess with the output, but in other cases it is. I suppose what it does is that if it shows you objects you "asked" as close to the top as possible, and then in the place you actually need them, it just references.

If you guys know what's wrong I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

PD: I've tried changing this option without success, it just makes things worse.

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

Comment: To be honest, I think you shouldn't store the teams within the sports, but add this functionality in a query instead. If you're obtaining the sport for a team, you will obtain the teams that belong the sport too, because those teams are stored in the sport as well.. You could query the teams and filter them based on a certain sport instead.
The reasoning that I'm using for this is as follows: A team can't exist without a sport, but a sport can exist without any teams. I'd say it's unnecessary to store the teams within the sport because of this, the teams already indicate the sport.

Comment: The problem is that EF generated this model, I can change it, of course, but if I could change the model's atributes for this specific controller it would be great. My main issue is the JSON containing objects I didn't ask for.

Comment: The teams have other classes too, many in fact, but they don't show up because I didn't request them. What seems to be happening is that if a team has an object that is in the JSON (anywhere else, let's say, the Entity), it shows it, with other objects within the Team it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from being too liberal with your data relationships. 
there are two ways to solve this:

1. get your data relationships in order. An example is your Sport object, it doesn't need to link to any teams. You have teams, great, each team has a sport linked to it, this is where it ends, there is a one to one relationship and nothing more. You can then easily build a query to show you all teams which have a certain sport linked to them.
2. Keep your structure as it is, but add some DTOs to return from your API, which to be fair is what you should be doing in the first place, whichever option you go to. One of the reasons you should never return Entity framework objects is because they come with all kinds of data you don't want.

So, in your query where you do your select, build a DTO, which has only the fields you want and then return that and your problem is solved.

`select e` becomes

```
select new EntityDTO {
     assign whatever fields you need here
}
```

This way you break your link to entity framework objects and all their dependencies.

Do a bit of reading for something like this maybe : https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/12568587/linq-to-sql-select-into-a-new-class